# VBA Freeze panes causes graphical issues

Tags: excel, vba, freeze

I really hope someone can share some knowledge about this, as google has not been kind to me.
I run a macro, which turns OFF at the beginning and ON at the end in reverse order:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts
Application.ScreenUpdating
Application.EnableEvents 
If Workbooks.Count > 0 Then 
    If Application.Calculation 
End if
```

The problem is after I run this macro, and I go to a sheet that has freeze panes, I get a weird graphical glitch on the top part of the frozen pane, that looks like a preview of another sheet.

If I manually save the file, the glitch goes away.
Can anyone tell me of a way to force refresh the sheet without saving the file?

If I save the file after the macro is done (as the last thing I do) the issue does not go away.

If I force recreate the freeze panes using the macro below, the problem still persists:

```
Sub FreezePanes_BySheetRef(Optional howManyRows, Optional howManyCols, Optional targetSh As Worksheet, Optional applyFilter As Boolean, Optional autoFit As Boolean, Optional Zoom, Optional turnOffGridlines As Boolean)
'ALLOWS FORMATTING WITHOUTH THE SHEET BEING SELECTED

'Handle missing
    If targetSh Is Nothing Then: Set targetSh = ActiveSheet
    If IsMissing(howManyRows) Then: howManyRows = 1
    If IsMissing(howManyCols) Then: howManyCols = 1
    If IsMissing(applyFilter) Then: applyFilter = False
    'If IsMissing(autoFit) Then: autoFit = False

    Dim previousSH
    Set previousSH = ActiveSheet    'RECORD PREVIOUS SHEET TO GET BACK TO IT
    Dim View As WorksheetView

    'On Error Resume Next
    With targetSh
        .Activate

        If Not IsMissing(Zoom) Then
            ActiveWindow.Zoom = Zoom
        End If
        For Each View In .Parent.Windows(1).SheetViews
            If View.Sheet.name = .name Then
                'ONLY IF SHEET WAS FOUND
                With View
                    .DisplayGridlines = Not turnOffGridlines  'BY DEFAULT = FALSE
                    With ActiveWindow
                        If .FreezePanes Then
                            .FreezePanes = False
                            .SplitColumn = 0
                            .SplitRow = 0
                        End If
                        .SplitColumn = howManyCols
                        .SplitRow = howManyRows
                        .FreezePanes = True
                    End With
                End With
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

        If applyFilter Then
            On Error Resume Next
            .AutoFilterMode = False
            .range(.cells(howManyRows, 1), .cells(howManyRows, getLastCol(1, 19, .name))).AutoFilter
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
        If autoFit Then
            .cells.Columns.autoFit
        End If

    End With

    previousSH.Activate    'GET BACK TO PREVIOUS SHEET
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found sort of a fix.
If you Hide/Unhide the sheet the graphical glitch goes away...

Answer (score 0):

Zooming in/out also fixes it. However, I'm still looking for a way to prevent it in the first place.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31283673)